# "deceptively easy": How to translate this controversially ambiguous English expression?

Tags: traduction

In English, the adverb "deceptively" used to qualify an adjective raises a red flag, as its interpretation is heavily context-dependent. For instance:

> Guessing how to pronounce anglicisms in French is **deceptively easy**.

- For some people, this sentence means: "It’s **anything but easy** despite its apparent easiness".
- While for others: "Despite appearances to the contrary, it’s **actually easy**".

I, for one, lean towards the former interpretation. I see some French speakers suggest the use of « d'une simplicité trompeuse », « trompeusement simple », or « faussement simple », but I’m not sure if they truly sound idiomatic to express the idea of "deceptively easy".

Personally, I want to say (at the risk of sounding somewhat verbose):

> L’ennui, c'est que la prononciation des anglicismes n’est pas forcément aussi évidente qu'elle n'en a l'air.

Comment: And I would say "aussi évidente qu'il n'y parait", but yours is perfectly correct too.

Comment: "d'une simplicité trompeuse" is probably my favorite, i.e. the one I would use most naturally, with the former meaning you are mentioning.

Comment: I think your translation is entirely good. It doesn't even sound verbose.

Comment: If a thing is deceptively F, then it is *in fact* F but this fact may be deceptive as to something *else*. Thus, if *Huckleberry Finn* is deceptively easy to understand, then it is in fact easy to understand, but one should not think the novel is *therefore* not profound, does not repay analysis, would have been easy to write, or whatever. Of course I am not saying this is the "right" way to look at the expression, but just one more way someone could use it.

Comment: @Catomic [Interesting post](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/25083/12918).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> L’ennui, c'est que la prononciation des anglicismes n’est pas forcément aussi évidente qu'elle n'en a l'air.

est tout à fait correct, bien que « forcément » ne soit pas nécessaire à mon avis.

« D'une simplicité trompeuse »  est probablement la façon la plus courante et la plus courante de rendre *deceptively easy* et convient très bien.

Personnellement et spontanément je rendrais *deceptively* par « sembler à première vue ». Ce qui pourrait être intégrer de la façon suivante:

> À première vue la prononciation des anglicismes en français semble facile / évidente **mais**...

On peut accentuer le décalage entre réalité et apparence en utilisant « pouvoir » (modalité introduisant l'incertitude) :

> À première vue la prononciation des anglicismes en français peut sembler facile / évidente **mais**...

« *A priori* » peut remplacer « à première vue ».

La proposition de @Frank est très bien aussi :

> La prononciation des anglicismes en français n'est pas aussi évidente qu'il n'y parait.

Comment: Hi. How do you express "a priori" in English? I've always been fuzzy on its exact meaning. I'm torn between "as far as I know" and "in theory / theoretically".

Comment: I think adverbial & adjectival uages are different in French & in English. As an adverb (which is the case here) in French  it means "sans bases expérimentales ou scientifiques", according to the wiktionary  as an adverb in English *a priori* means "In a way based on theoretical deduction rather than empirical observation."

Comment: "A priori" exists in English too.

Comment: @ Frank Did I say something different?

Comment: Is "a priori" a common expression in French? The only people who are going to say "a priori" in English are those who say "a fortiori," and they all live in ivy-clad buildings.

Comment: @Catomic I gather it's much more common in French. Not used by everyone of course but its use is not restricted to those who've been to a *Grande École* (France's equivalent to Ivy-League). It will be understood by anyone who's had a lycée education, and can be used in everyday conversation (not only in formal speech) as an adverb to mean "presumed". As an adjective meaning "based on scientific deduction" I gather its use is restricted to philosophy and scientific language.   A compared use of the term in English & French would be interesting.